# Creating JavaScript search boxes for custom sites that create popup windows showing the search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I would like to create a JavaScript that adds a search box to HTML pages, then with the input it first URL encodes it and adds it to a URL (e.g., http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term= could be the base URL) and creates a new popup Window opening the end URL (i.e., the result of the addition of the URL encoded input and the base URL). e.g., if the Input for a PubMed search (the same URL as in the example above) is `nicotine[TI] AND review[PT]` then the output URL that the new window would open to would be:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=nicotine%5BTI%5D+AND+review%5BPT%5D.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var Form = $("#myForm");   
 Form.onsubmit = function() {
 var baseUrl = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=';
 var search = $("#input").val();
 var Url = baseUrl + search ;
 var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(Url);
 var w = window.open(encodedUrl ,'Popup','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=500');
 this.target = 'Popup';
 alert(encodedUrl);
};

<form id="myForm" >
 <input type="text" id="input">
 <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Calling that script Search box.js and calling it by a HTML file:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Search box for PubMed</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Search box.js"></script>
</body>
</html>` gives an empty page.